# How to compare elements in list, but exclude tail of elements, if duplicates exist: make new list that includes the tail of the element

Tags: python, list, duplicates, compare

I have looked around here, and found a ton of list comparing methods. but not one that cover my specific question...so here it goes:

I have a list:

```
currentList = ["Blur1['size']: $gui index:1", "Blur1['size']: $gui index:3",
               "Blur2['mix']: $gui?4:8"]
```

I want to remove duplicates, but I don't want to include `' index:1'` or `' index:3'` or `'index'` with any number behind it for that matter.

Then I want to make a new list, and if any duplicates are found in `currentList`, I would like to make a new list with only one element of the duplicates, but I would also like the new element to include the numbers found in the duplicates.

Essentially when the new list is created, I would like the difference to be like this:

```
currentList = ["Blur1['size']: $gui index:1", "Blur1['size']: $gui index:3",
               "Blur2['mix']: $gui?4:8"]
```

and the new list created after comparing elements in `currentList`.

```
newList = ["Blur1['size']: $gui 13", "Blur2['mix']: $gui?4:8"]
```

The new list only have 1 element of `"Blur1['size']: $gui"`
but it has the combined numbers 1 and 3 added to the tail of the string, coming from the duplicates in `currentList`.

I know how to remove duplicates leaving out the index, I could do that with a if test on if `'index'` exists in the string.. the problem I'm facing is that I want to keep the numbers behind `'index'` and recreate 1 single element with all the numbers behind the `'index'` string.

I hope this makes sense. I would greatly appreciate any help on this python problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach would be using an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) (to keep the same order of `currentList`) with [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and some [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

current_list = ["Blur1['size']: $gui index:1", "Blur1['size']: $gui index:3",
                "Blur2['mix']: $gui?4:8"]

temp = [item.split('index:') for item in current_list]

d = OrderedDict()

for i in temp:
    if len(i) == 2:
        d[i[0]] = i[1] if i[0] not in d else '{}{}'.format(d[i[0]], i[1])
    else:
        d[i[0]] = ""

new_list = ['{}{}'.format(*item) for item in d.items()]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> new_list
["Blur1['size']: $gui 13", "Blur2['mix']: $gui?4:8"]
```

Comment: Thanks @ettanany, very useful for keeping the order. Much appreciated!

Comment: You're welocme! Please let me know if it does not work for your generic use case, because I tested it only for your above `currentList`. For example, I do not know what you expect if you have `"Blur2['mix']: $gui?4:8"`, `"Blur2['mix']: $gui?4:9"` and `"Blur2['mix']: $gui?3:5"` in your list.

Comment: Seems to be working fine after a quick test. I'll let you know if I run into problems after more testing with different parameters. Thanks!